# How to get first two elements of a stack in Swift?

Tags: swift, stack

I've got this stack implementation from raywenderlich website, but I would like to implement a method that peeks the first two elements of the stack. Of course, receiving its values

```
struct Stack<Element> {
  fileprivate var array: [Element] = []
  
  mutating func push(_ element: Element) {
    array.append(element)
  }
  
  mutating func pop() -> Element? {
    return array.popLast()
  }
  
  func peek() -> Element? {
    return array.last
  }
}
```

How can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: `array.prefix(2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

struct Stack<Element> {
  fileprivate var array: [Element] = []
  
  mutating func push(_ element: Element) {
    array.append(element)
  }
  
  mutating func pop() -> Element? {
    return array.popLast()
  }
  
  func peek() -> Element? {
    return array.last
  }
    
  func peekTwoElements() -> [Element]? {
    let length = array.count
    return (length >= 2 ? [array[length-1], array[length-2]] : nil)
  }
}
```